# Properties of upper level sets of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $h_1$ and $h_2$ be two differentiable convex functions on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\bar x\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $h_1(\bar x)=h_2(\bar x)=0$ and $\nabla h_1(\bar x)=\lambda \nabla h_2(\bar x)$ for some $\lambda >0$. Prove that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $\bar x$ such that one of the following two sets contains the other one: 
$\{x\in U: h_1(x) \geq 0\}$ and $\{x\in U: h_2(x) \geq 0\}$.

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: 
$$n=3, \quad \bar{x}=(1,0,0), \quad h_1(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-1, \quad h_2(x,y,z) = x^2+ \frac12 y^2+2z^2-1.$$

In fact in small neighborhoods of $\bar{x}$ in $xy$ plane $\{x:h_2(x)\geq 0\}$ is strictly smaller than $\{x:h_1(x)\geq 0\}$ (because for $y\neq 0$, $h_1(x,y,0)>h_2(x,y,0)$ ) and in small neighborhoods in $xz$ plane $\{x:h_2(x)\geq 0\}$ is strictly bigger.

There is also a 2-dimensional counterexample but I couldn't find explicit formulas.

[image]

Comment: @ Mostafa: In your answer, "bigger" should be "smaller" and vice versa. Moreover, It should be better if you can give a sequence argument?

Comment: @Richkent I applied the edit. I think the argument is evident and there is no need to give a sequence argument, though it can be constructed easily.